# CSS: How to remove enter from HTML?

Tags: html, css

Consider the following Html:

```
<div class="one">
    <span>1. test</span>
    <span>test</span>
</div>
<div class="two">
    <span>2. test</span><span>test</span>
</div>
```

The result is:

```
1. test test
2. testtest
```

I need a piece of CSS that will remove the space (or enter) between the two words of the 1st line so it will look like the 2nd line. **Is it possible to remove the space with CSS?**

***Clarification**: I'm searching for a solution **without** having to adjust the html!*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.one {word-spacing: -4px;}
.one span {word-spacing: normal;}
```

If there are only spans in the div, remove (or neutralise) the word-spacing from the div then reset it to normal for the actual spans

#### See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/Cq42N/)

#### Update:

As rightly pointed out by @Alohci in the comments [on their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043614/css-how-to-remove-enter-from-html/6043796#6043796) the space between words is font-size dependant so it might be better to use `-0.25em` instead of `-4px`. this is a quarter of the default (4px being a quarter of 'default' 16px) note this is also font-family dependant, however it should be much more robust to use the `em`s

Comment: @Craig,note I've updated the 'em` value.. it's not 1em but a quarter or thereabouts

Comment: Love the idea and sounds like a valid use of CSS.

Comment: When should I use -0.25em or -4px?

Comment: @Kees use the `ems` it should cover both - the default (screen) browser setting is 16px for font-size, therefore the "quarter" is 4px  but once the default in manipulated either by user or by OS or by CSS then `0.25em` is the same as `25%`

Answer (score 3):

`div.one span { float:left; }`

http://jsfiddle.net/7CRYP/

Comment: So which method do you think is better, yours or @clairsuzy?

Comment: @Craig, both will work :) `float` may require you to do wee bit of extra work clearing the floats - `word-spacing` might require more elements to be reset

Comment: @Craig - well @clairsuzy's solution is font size dependent. I'd use `-1em` rather than `-4px`, but other than that it looks a good solution - just use whatever works for you.

Comment: @clairesuzy @alohci Thanks for your additional thoughts! I think I like the float method better because it does not relate to the font-size...but plus one to you both!

Comment: @Alohci thanks for reminder about font-sizing, have updated my answer, @Craig thank you!

Comment: @clairesuzy @alohci thanks for the additional additional info..still both good answers but I think @clairesuzy's answer now makes more sense to me after looking up the details of em since you do not have to actually specify the font-size... @craig silly programmer.

Answer (score 2):

basically you can't remove enters with css. You could do it by script or prevent them from appearing by adjusting the source.

Comment: That's true... it is a dirty hack, but the answer given by @clairsuzy will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do that in your HTML code:

```
<div class="one">
    <span>1. test</span><!--
    --><span>test</span>
</div>
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/sh2Pr/

Comment: That would work, but the idea is to find a solution that works without having to modify any html.

Comment: You **cannot** remove the space with CSS, in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Depends how dirty you feel - http://jsfiddle.net/sh2Pr/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove `White Spaces` between the words it is not possible using CSS because `White Space` is a character. If you decrease spacing between the words it will condense whole text. Other option is to use JavaScript or Jquery.

Comment: @Thomas - see: [word-spacing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-word-spacing) - the white space between words is not a word it's: _"This property specifies spacing behavior between words."_